Unitys canvas keeps scaling and changing size
I was trying to make an inventory UI but came across this problem where whenever I selected either the text or the canvas itself the canvas would change size to a small square. It would change bact to the original size when the camera was updated(seleccting it, changing view to play, changing shaders, etc). I have tried disabling components, chaning the canvas scaler element and pretty much everything that could impact it. The only thing that i found was that if I disabled the canvas component the scaling wouldn't happen. This also made the text invisible because there was no actual canvas.
https://youtu.be/puBMLcI3oAE
Unity version 2022.3.19f1

I would delete the entire canvas object and create a new one. Does it behave normally in play mode? Unity UI is not perfect. Caused (and continues to) a few issues...

Do you have more than one game tab opened?
